# Inserir os parágrafos de um arquivo JSON dentro de uma DIV

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Tenho um arquivo [json](/questions/tagged/json) que em seu conteúdo ele contém parágrafos. Esses parágrafos são separados por `\n` mas quando eu insiro o conteúdo os parágrafos não são separados e ao invés de quebra de linha eu tenho um espaço na `DIV`. Ao meu ver a minha solução seria converter os `\n` em quebras de linha que o `HTML` entende (`<p>` ou `<br>`). Qual o método mais correto a ser usado?

Comment: Perguntas sobre o que é mais correto são sempre mais complicadas. levam a respostas subjetivas. Não estou dizendo que a pergunta em sua forma geral não pode ser respondida. Estou vendo muitas perguntas justamente sobre o que é mais correto e nem sempre é fácil dizer isso. Dar uma solução correta fica mais fácil. Se você não sabe qual é o mais correto, como vai escolher a resposta a ser aceita?

Comment: existem inúmeras formas de tratar a minha necessidade acima, o que procuro é qual a forma mais utilizada, com a intenção de fazer uso de algum padrão geral ou de métodos mais atuais e viáveis @bigown.

Comment: Sua questão está sendo discutida aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/76/o-que-fazer-quando-os-votos-parecem-incoerentes-com-o-conteudo. Seria interessante se você pudesse tentar melhorá-la para evitar interpretações erradas.

Comment: função nl2br do php, escrita em javascript: http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Qual o método mais correto a ser usado?

Mais correto em que sentido? Performance? Assertividade? Legibilidade?

Enfim, normalmente utiliza-se um [replace tradicional do JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170) (como visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/1316620), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532796/1316620) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5076492/1316620)...).

Então no seu caso bastaria:

```
>>> "string\ncom\nquebras\nde\nlinha".replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
"string<br />com<br />quebras<br />de<br />linha"
```

---

Agora, para substituir **quebras de linha***, e não apenas `\n` é melhor utilizar:

```
>>> "Quebra de linha *nix.\nQuebra de linha Mac.\rQuebra de linha Windows.\r\n".replace(/\r\n|[\r\n]/g, '<br />');
"Quebra de linha *nix.<br />Quebra de linha Mac.<br />Quebra de linha Windows.<br />"
```

* *Existem outros dois tipos de quebra de linha além do estilo *nix (`\n`): `\r` (estilo Mac antigo) e `\r\n` (estilo Windows).*

Comment: usei `str.replace(/\n/g,'<br>')`

Comment: @LeandroLUK Se tiver garantia de que suas quebras de linha são `\n` é o melhor mesmo (:

Comment: qual seria melhor quebra de linha a ser usada? (melhor qual a mais usada `\n` ou `\r`)

Comment: Se é você que está montando a string sugiro `\n`; já que `\r` é muito raro, salvo engano meu só Macintosh antigos utilizam; e `\r\n` apesar de ser comum em ambientes Windows é desnecessário, um caractere basta e é mais simples, já cansei de ver gente confundindo com `\n\r` (que não existe).

Answer (score 3):

Para substituir por `<br/>`, faça:

```
result = result.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

Para substituir por `<p>...</p>`:

```
result = "<p>" + result.replace(/\n/g, "</p><p>") + "</p>";
```

A melhor abordagem depende do que você quer, mas eu iria pela tag `<p>` porque você poderia formatar com CSS e manipular mais facilmente com javascript.

Comment: Na sua resposta somente substituirá 1 ocorrência.

Comment: @Guerra, Você não viu o `/g` ali?

Comment: `\n` só é mostrado no final da do parágrafo @Gerra. se usasse como você informou a tag `<p></p>` ele iria deixar um parágrafo em branco perdido no código, e talvez desformataria a página com um espaço sobrando.

Comment: @downvoters: favor comentar por quê de votar down.

Comment: @LeandroLUK ele ta substituindo `\n` por `</p><p>` observe que é o contrario do que você comentou. E incluindo `<p>` no inicio e `</p>` no final vai corretamente separar em parágrafos.

Comment: Exemplo no jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RLz6Z/

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando os métodos [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) também chega ao resultado:

```
>>> "Primeiro parágrafo.\nSegundo parágrafo.".split('\n').join('<br/>');
"Primeiro parágrafo.<br/>Segundo parágrafo."
```

```js
let res = "Primeiro parágrafo.\nSegundo parágrafo.".split('\n').join('<br/>');
document.querySelector('#resultado').innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score -5):

Usando regular expression é possivel desta forma:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />");
```

Comment: É Java ou Javascript?

Comment: **Não existe função `replaceAll` em JavaScript**. Sugestão de leitura: [Como fazer replaceAll no javascript](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/170/como-fazer-replaceall-no-javascript).