# Quando usar Graceful Degradation e quando usar Progressive Enhancement?

Tags: aplicação-web, arquitetura-de-software, ux, cross-browser

Ao se criar um site ou aplicação web, sempre há o problema do que fazer quando nem todos os browsers implementam todas as funcionalidades desejáveis. Pelo que tenho lido, há duas principais maneiras de se lidar com isso:

- *Graceful Degradation* ("Degradação Suave") - Desenvolve-se pensando num ambiente o mais completo possível, mas assegurando-se que se a funcionalidade X ou Y estiver ausente o site ainda funcione da melhor forma possível sem ela.
- *Progressive Enhancement* ("Enriquecimento Progressivo") - Desenvolve-se pensando num ambiente o mais básico possível, e acrescenta-se características extra caso a presença da funcionalidade X ou Y seja detectada.

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma delas? Há situações em que uma é mais adequada que a outra, ou é apenas questão de preferência? Estou interessado principalmente no aspecto da manutenabilidade: à medida que características novas vão sendo introduzidas aos browsers, e versões antigas dos mesmos caem em desuso, quais as implicações disso num site/aplicação desenvolvido segundo essas estratégias?

Comment: Acredito que o estabelecimento de pré-requisitos necessários é a melhor opção, e definir o que deve existir para que a aplicação funcione corretamente é o que faço. Ex: Se alguém abrir no `IE` eu notifico logo que é melhor abrir com o browser X,Y,Z pelos motivos G,H,Y. Se nas próximas versões os quesitos aumentarem e o browser Y não suportar, aplico a mesma técnica. Só não sei se isto se enquadra em qual "filosofia". Acredito que as coisas ficariam mais facilitadas se todos os browser tivessem no mesmo nível e features muito idênticas e padronizadas. Minha opinião.

Comment: @Cold Isso seria um caso de ***Un**graceful Degradation* hehe (brincadeira, é lógico que se você teve o esforço de detectar o browser e notificar o usuário do problema, então é *graceful* sim)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O @utluiz tem razão quando diz que *tecnicamente não há diferença*. O antagonismo entre os dois termos (não são técnicas, estão mais para filosofias) hoje não é tão forte quanto já foi, e é preciso lembrar de onde eles vêm. Um é na verdade uma evolução do outro, e o que se usa atualmente é o resultado dessa evolução, e de certo modo uma combinação dos dois.

### Graceful degradation

Quando surgiu a expressão *graceful degradation*, não havia suporte padronizado aos recursos mais básicos, e imperava o caos. O browser com a maior fatia do mercado tinha inúmeros bugs de CSS, e não suportava as APIs para JavaScript do W3C. O ciclo de atualização dos browsers era bem mais lento que hoje. Muitos sites e aplicações quebravam em um ou outro navegador – sem falar em dispositivos móveis, que eram bem mais rudimentares e bem menos presentes.

Quando havia suporte a dois ou mais navegadores, isso era feito com técnicas de detecção de browsers e versões específicas de browsers, o que logo se mostrou insustentável. Então veio a ênfase numa solução mais elegante, daí *graceful*. Na prática, veio a troca do *browser sniffing* pelo *feature detection*. Em vez de codificar para um ou outro navegador, verifica-se se o navegador do usuário suporta um determinado recurso, e decide-se como reagir a sua presença ou ausência.

### Progressive enhancement

Esse modelo foi um passo adiante em direção a uma web *cross-browser*. Surgiram *polyfills* e *shims*, "tampões" para recursos não suportados, nivelando melhor o que era possível fazer. Paralelamente, foram ganhando espaço o movimento pela marcação semântica, as técnicas de posicionamento em mecanismos de busca, os dispositivos móveis. Isso logo levou o foco do desenvolvimento a passar dos recursos para o contéudo. E só aí surgiu a corrente do *progressive enhancement*, que representou exatamente essa mudança de ênfase: da degradação (dos recursos) ao aprimoramento (do conteúdo). A distinção pode parecer sutil, mas é importante. O espírito antes era entregar conteúdo "feio" se não houvesse outro jeito. Passou a ser entregar conteúdo "pelado" e acrescentar camadas para quem puder aproveitá-las.

A técnica que possibilita isso não mudou muito, continou sendo *feature detection*, somada a um cuidado maior com a marcação. Isso foi ficando mais simples de concretizar conforme os browsers foram evoluindo.

### Na prática

Ao iniciar o desenvolvimento de um site ou aplicação web, você sempre irá levar em conta:

- O seu público-alvo
- O conteúdo que será apresentado
- Os recursos que esse conteúdo exige

Repare que eu disse *exige* no último item. Por exemplo, se você cria o site de uma biblioteca JavaScript para manipulação de canvas, é óbvio que as páginas de demonstração da biblioteca dependerão de suporte ao canvas. Usando feature-detection, você pode mostrar um screenshot e/ou uma mensagem dizendo que o canvas é um requisito, mas não faz  sentido implementar uma versão funcional sem canvas (por exemplo, em Flash) se o propósito da sua biblioteca não for substituir o canvas quando ele não estiver disponível. Já as páginas de documentação da biblioteca, sem exemplos dela em funcionamento, devem funcionar em mais browsers e dispositivos, pois impõem menos limitações.

Ou seja: o seu conteúdo é quem manda (*content is king*). Isso está no espírito do *progressive enhancement*, mas a aplicação prática (exibir conteúdo alternativo ou aparência alternativa quando não há suporte a *X*) pode igualmente ser vista como *graceful degradation*.

Comment: +1 A resposta do utluiz é boa, mas após lê-la minha dúvida permaneceu... Esta já é mais esclarecedora, principalmente ao contextualizar com um exemplo (o do canvas). Uma dúvida que não tem nada a ver: sempre usei "polyfill" e "shim" como sinônimos, tem alguma diferença entre eles?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu também não sei direito a diferença, mas entendi que polyfill é um subtipo de shim (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671015/825789). Pra complicar, [um colega aqui do site um dia me falou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170/como-fazer-replaceall-no-javascript/3716#comment4671_3716) de "prolyfill" :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Acabei de esbarrar num artigo que menciona a origem do termo *polyfill*: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/polyfilling-doesnt-difficult/

Answer (score 17):

## Tecnicamente não há diferença

Com ambas as abordagens é possível implementar compatibilidade com qualquer navegador, em qualquer versão. A diferença entre elas é como de uma abordagem *top-down* ou *bottom-up*, mas no fim você pode alcançar os mesmos resultados.

## A estratégia pode influenciar na mentalidade da equipe

Por exemplo, a *Graceful Degradation* ("Degradação Suave") irá de alguma forma priorizar os navegadores mais novos, já que o raciocínio é: *implemente o mais novo e, caso não dê, use o plano B para manter a compatibilidade*.

Já o *Progressive Enhancement* ("Enriquecimento Progressivo") irá produzir o efeito oposto, colocando a compatibilidade em primazia: *vamos fazer o mais simples e, quando possível, melhoramos um pouco*.

## Limitações que fazem diferença

Infelizmente, hoje ainda é necessário que façamos testes nos vários navegadores e dispositivos diferentes para realmente garantir o funcionamento adequado de um sistema. E creio ser inevitável que a equipe acabe focando nas funções mais imediatas à sua realidade.

Então nos deparamos com duas restrições:

- O desenvolvedor dará preferência a um ambiente específico para codificar, o que inevitavelmente aumenta a chance de erros nos ambientes "secundários" com que ele teve menos contato.
- A limitação de tempo e recursos faz com que não seja possível realizar baterias de testes adequadas em todos os cenários possíveis.

## Conclusão

Com tudo isso, minha conclusão é que a técnica de detecção de recursos de um navegador (ou a falta dele) não é mais importante do que a correta definição de uma estratégia  de desenvolvimento e de testes.

Como em geral não se pode ter tudo, então é necessário uma definição clara do público alvo e dos cenários mais prováveis de uso do sistema.

Se a tendência for que os usuários usem navegadores mais modernos, então vale mais a pena começar assumindo as funcionalidades mais novas. Quando o navegador não possuir alguma funcionalidade, aplica-se a Degradação Suave. Se der algum problema, pelo menos vai atingir a minoria dos usuários.

Já em outro cenário, imaginando talvez um órgão governamental ou uma grande empresa, onde a atualização dos navegadores anda a passos bem lentos, é melhor usar menos dos novos recursos e, em certos cenários, pode-se então enriquecer o sistema. Do mesmo modo, poucos usuários serão impactados caso haja algum problema por causa disso.