# Carregamento de "páginas" externas via AJAX. O Google vai indexar?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ajax, seo

Alguns falando para usar `#!`, outros dizem para usar *History API* e outros dizem que o *Google* já executa JavaScript.

Estou fazendo um projeto cujas páginas são carregadas num *container* principal.

Todo *link* é uma âncora mas o que está depois do *hash* é realmente um caminho. Meu JavaScript é programado para detectar eventos de troca de *hash*, então ele pega o caminho subtraindo a *hash* e carrega o conteúdo do arquivo no *container* principal.

Vejam o *script*, é muito simples!

```
    (function ($) {

        function hashNavigate() {

            var url = window.location.href;
            var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#'));
                hash = hash.replace("#", "");

            if( /#/.test(url) ) { // se houver Hash (se nao for pagina inicial)

                if(!$("#mainRow").html().length) { // se mainRow estiver vazia, apenas carrega o conteúdo

                    $("#mainRow").load(hash);
                } else {

                    $("#mainRow").html("").load(hash); // senão, apaga o conteúdo e carrega o novo em seguida
                }
            }       
        }

        hashNavigate() // executa a primeira vez 

        $(window).on("hashchange", hashNavigate) // armazena no evento

    })(jQuery);
```

Desta forma o meu *site* será indexado?

**obs**: Todo documento externo carregado no *container* principal não possuem uma estrutura HTML completa, apenas o que deve ser carregado dentro dela e uma *tag* de script.

Comment: Da uma lida sobre o _escaped_fragment_: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Mesmo que a Google eventualmente execute código em JavaScript não conte que esta execução seja perfeita e reproduza exatamente o que você espera.

De fato a [documentação atual](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) do buscador da Google diz claramente para você preparar conteúdo que dependa de AJAX para ser lido também sem o uso de JS. Isto é bom para usuários que não possuem JS habilitado no navegador como para o *crawler* de indexação. Se eles dizem isto, você vai confiar em algo extra não documentado que eles possam estar oferecendo?

A recomendação deles (e eu digo que não deveria ser só por causa deles) é fazer páginas que não dependa de JS e depois colocar o que precisa para apenas melhorar a usabilidade da página. Isto é conhecido por [*progressive enhancement](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101)*.

O que eles mandam fazer é ter conteúdo acessível que não depende de JS e mesmo *links* para páginas que serão montadas com AJAX também estejam disponíveis na forma tradicional.

Fora isto, só tem um jeito de ter certeza de saber se seu caso específico vai dar certo, fazendo e ver se ele indexa como você espera.

Talvez alguém com mais conhecimento que eu sobre isto venha aqui e garanta que vai indexar, eu não arriscaria dizer isto. Posso estar enganado e posso não ter entendido a descrição da pergunta (até porque não tem todos detalhes sobre o uso deste código) mas eu acho que o código é complexo demais (o que ele faz e não a escrita dele) para o Google executar corretamente.

Veja também o [guia da Google sobre AJAX](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).