# O que são aplicações isomorphic?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, single-page-application

Em diversos artigos e métodos de desenvolvimento de aplicações modernas, me deparo com *isomorphic applications*.

Mas o que realmente é? Normalmente definem como "o melhor do *client/server side* juntos". Então, como são essas aplicações *isomorphic*? Quem faz o *router*? Quem rendeniza as *views*? *Client* ou *Server*?

Renderização e *router* em *client* é bem típico de SPA (Single Page Applications).

Comment: Em suma: são aplicações que usam o mesmo código tanto no cliente quanto no servidor. O conceito vem ganhando força com o Node.js.

Comment: @Kazzkiq mas isso é ruim demais =/ e quem não usa node.js? além que para aplicações de grande escala, não sei se node.js seria boa ideia, uma que custo de dev js é maior, outra que a própria linguagem é instável, por causa dos navegadores...

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Você deve estar falando [dessa página](http://isomorphic.net/). É um desses termos que um grupo de desenvolvedores querem fazer colar, só o tempo vai dizer o que vai acontecer.

O significado parece que você já sabe. É uma técnica em que tanto a parte do servidor quanto do cliente compartilham código. Em tese isto traz vantagens, e é claro que existem desvantagens.

Eles partem de um pressuposto perigoso de que o Google consegue indexar as páginas todas renderizadas no cliente, o que [não é uma verdade absoluta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77808/101) e ignora os demais buscadores.

Além disto me parece que colocar não só a renderização, como a roteirização no cliente, tem problemas para controlar o conteúdo. Eu nem imagino como você pode confiar em algo tão importante que é feito no cliente e tem impacto no servidor. Devem ter alguma solução mas deve começar ter suas desvantagens.

Então pode até ser útil para aplicações, mas não para *sites*. Não é a toa que o A do SPA é de *applications* e não de é um S de *sites*.

A ideia do SPA é interessante e esta técnica leva isto ao extremo deixando muito pouco para o Node.js resolver no lado do servidor.

Ela esbarra no problema que a tecnologia atual não funciona tão bem assim com SPA e muitas aplicações não conseguem se dar bem com o extremismo de deixar o servidor apenas lidar como um fornecedor de API e mais nada.

Por isso mesmo parece que poucas pessoas compraram a ideia até agora.

A vantagem óbvia é o purismo de usar apenas uma linguagem, uma única biblioteca coerente, além de não sobrecarregar o servidor, em tese.

Comment: obrigado por responder, mas está bem confusa sua resposta, o que entendi pela sua resposta foi: É um método que estão querendo impor, para ser algo como opção de uma SPA, que a rendenização e router é toda feita no cliente (pela sua preocupação) e por ultimo "usar apenas uma linguagem", o que isso significa que tanto o client/server teria apenas uma tecnologia (que por si é o javascript, via node.js) mas ainda assim não entendi a questão exata de isophophic app

Comment: É isto aí. Não tem muito mais a dizer a não ser descrever tudo como funciona a tecnologia. O que precisaria de páginas. Então faça uma pergunta específica. Talvez seja algo mais simples do que você imagina e está tentando achar que não existe.

Comment: quando li a respeito, fiquei na dúvida, se esse tipo de aplicação a rendenização e router é feita no client, assim como as SPA, e imaginei como seria a implementção usando outro server side, mas se é só via node.js/express ou coisas do genero, simplesmente perdi o interesse, rsrs

Comment: Não é que precisa ser via Node, mas hoje é a forma mais viável. Mas entenda isto apenas com uma técnica nova e não uma tecnologia nova.

Comment: se pensarmos que tudo isso que fazemos todo dia nada mais é que brincar com 0 e 1, a tecnologia é sempre a mesma.

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário @EduardoSeixas rsrs

Comment: @Rod, só quis dizer que a nossa área (desenvolvimento) nos últimos anos foram adicionados vários conceitos, técnicas e formas de tratar assuntos já existentes em linguagens. Nem sempre algo novo pode ser considerado uma nova tecnologia, apenas um refinamento melhor de conceitos e técnicas de programação.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas sim, isso é...o conceito das "spa" já existe a alguns anos na verdade, vem lá do extjs...mas agora que está se popularizando graças a alguns fw(angularjs, emberjs,etc) , e também agora essas isomorphic, então fiquei curioso em conhecer

Answer (score 0):

Antigamente, com asp, php e servlets, os htmls eram totalmente montados no servidor, o que, obviamente, gera um consume desnecessário. Imagine que o próprio computador do cliente pode fazer isso por você. Foi assim que cresceram tecnologias como JQuery e AngularJS.

Dado que você precisa se especializar em JavaScript e seus Frameworks, muitas empresas tem adotado, por exemplo NodeJS e afins. O próprio Java tem o [Nashorm](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html), uma engine de JavaScript.

O AirBnb, que tem sido referência em tecnologia, [publicou um artigo explicando tudo o que vc quer saber sobre o assunto](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/).