# Utilização do React em backend e pequenos projetos

Tags: javascript, html, react

É possível integrar a aplicação React com alguma linguagem back end?

Posso aplicar o React em projetos pequenos ou só quando há necessidade?

O React veio para quebrar o paradigma de desenvolvimento web padrão, onde eu crio arquivos separados, cada um com uma tarefa, por exemplo, `index.html` contendo todo o HTML do site e um arquivo `javascript.js` contendo todo o JavaScript que irei utilizar na página? Pois pelo que percebi, com React eu junto HTML e JavaScript na mesma página.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

> É possível integrar a aplicação React com alguma linguagem back end?

React é só uma forma de manipular o *front-end*, então tudo o que pode fazer no *front-end* está disponível quando usa React, inclusive acessar o *back-end*. De fato ele tem algumas facilidades para trabalhar melhor com oque vem do *back-end* e como enviar para ele.

Se é isso que está falando sobre integrar, então sim. Se está falando em usar o React no *back-end*, eu diria que sim, mas é um pouco diferente, é possível aproveitar partes. Isto é uma técnica [isomórfica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81205/101) e pode ser obtida mais facilmente com ferramentas como o [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). Pode ver mais em um [artigo](https://hackernoon.com/isomorphic-universal-boilerplate-react-redux-server-rendering-tutorial-example-webpack-compenent-6e22106ae285). E um [exemplo](https://github.com/danielstern/isomorphic-react). E [outro](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example).

> Posso aplicar o React em projetos pequenos ou só quando há necessidade?

Poder sempre pode, mas precisa analisar se deve. Eu evitaria coisas pesadas como o React para coisas simples e pequenas, mas depende do objetivo. Eu tenho uma tendenciosidade a não usar *frameworks* a não ser quando se se prove muito útil, e tendo a usar algo mais leve como o [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) até que precisa de algo mais completo.

O React é só uma ferramenta do que você está descrevendo sobre [SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212952/101).