# Quando usar e não usar AJAX no envio de formulários?

Tags: php, ajax, ux

Se eu tiver um formulário gigante de questões, mandar via AJAX é a melhor forma?

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST">
    <!--vários Questionarios aqui-->
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
    url: "algumaurl.php",
    success: function(resposta){
       alert(resposta);
    }
});
```

No URL `algumaurl.php` teria um *update* em um determinado `id` e dentro desta página teria um `echo` de resposta (`Erro na conexão` ou `OK`).

```
    success: function(resposta){
       if(resposta== "Erro na conexão"){
           alert("Erro ao inserir dados");
       } else if(resposta== "OK"){
           alert("Formulario ok");
           window.location = "https://www.youtube.com";
       }
    }
```

Se eu fizer usando `action="algumaurl.php"` terei problemas se o formulário já estiver preenchido (perderei todos os dados posteriormente preenchidos) em caso de erro, não é?

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela set nome=\"algo\" WHERE ID=$id");

if($update === false){   
    $mensagem ="Erro na conexão";
    header("location: ../pagina-2.php?mensagem=$mensagem");
} else{
    $mensagem ="OK";
    header("location: https://www.youtube.com");
}
```

Comment: Minha resposta é: _Você decide_. rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: @WallaceMaxters E a minha é, *O cliente decide*. :D

Comment: Em tempo: quando eu digo "cliente" eu não me refiro só ao Seu Zé dono da padaria. Cliente de software pode ser uma entidade complexa com muitas formas possíveis - se este for o caso, tomar decisões por ele pode resultar em complexidade desnecessária, atraso, prejuízo, desperdício e outras mazelas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não existem casos claros onde deve ou não usar. Depende da experiência que você quer dar ao usuário.

Antes de mais nada, um dos erros mais comuns, mas muito comum mesmo, que eu vejo nas aplicações que usam AJAX ou outras tecnologias semelhantes é que não há um [*fallback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152503/101). Ou seja, se por alguma razão a tecnologia não estiver disponível, a página não funciona. A primeira coisa que deve [se preocupar é se o envio com HTML simples está funcionando perfeitamente em todas as situações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101). Depois pense em dar uma experiência um pouco melhor se ele estiver disponível. Mas não deixe a página parar de funcionar porque o navegador não suporta a tecnologia.

Embora seja gosto, eu acho que esta técnica vale até mesmo quando o *fallback* não é exigido pelo cliente, onde pode-se garantir que o recurso está disponível. Acho que o custo é muito baixo e evita um monte de dor de cabeça futura. É uma questão de metodologia e organização. O custo da desorganização costuma ser maior. Claro que a experiência de cada um fará escolher o melhor caminho.

Não sou contra quem não quer fazer o *fallback* quando ele não é realmente necessário de acordo com os requisitos. Só acho um caminho pior e mais desvantajoso. E o cliente nem sempre tem razão. Na maior parte das vezes eu decido por ele. Ele decide quando ele tem conhecimento, é razoável ou eu preciso do dinheiro :P Você fará o que for mais adequado para você.

## Funcionamento do AJAX

A única grande vantagem que o AJAX traz é que não precisa carregar outra página, ou a mesma outra vez, para enviar os dados e ter uma resposta. Isto é feito de forma transparente para o usuário. Dá uma impressão melhor, costuma ser mais rápido (já vi gente conseguir deixar mais lento) e pode reduzir o volume de dados trafegado. Mas nada muito importante. A experiência é que conta mesmo.

Eventualmente o *script* PHP que receberá a requisição precisa ser adaptado para atender a necessidade do AJAX, mas não mude de forma que inviabilize o acesso normal. Se for o caso, crie dois *scripts*, um para atender o formulário por envio normal gerando uma página completa e outro mandando só os dados de confirmação que a operação foi bem-sucedida e informar algo mais que seja relevante. Se souber fazer o trabalho é quase o mesmo.

## Vantagem no seu caso

Mandar cada questão respondida realmente pode ser bem interessante.

A perda ou não dos dados dependerá do seu *script* PHP saber manipular isso. Ele terá que persistir em algum lugar (banco de dados, memória, etc.), ter controle da sessão, etc. Terá que controlar o estado do formulário não estar completamente preenchido, ter políticas de coleta de lixo se um formulário for abandonado no meio. Enfim, tem várias coisas para pensar se quiser dar uma experiência boa ao usuário.

Já imaginou se houver algum problema no momento do envio e não tiver AJAX? A perda é enorme. Com o AJAX feito do jeito que está pensando, ou aproveita a parte de já foi feita, ou impede o usuário continuar perdendo seu tempo em algo que servirá para nada.

Isso tudo é complicado, ter um *fallback* é simples. Por isto muitos sites preferem nem ter AJAX. O custo de colocar este recurso do jeito certo aumenta, mas aí quem paga o custo é o usuário que terá uma experiência bem pior.

Se estiver fazendo algo real, mesmo que para testes ainda, e for tendo dúvidas específicas, você pesquisa se já tem aqui ou pergunte.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Incorreto. Um aplicativo ter que usar Ajax, e ter que continuar funcionando se o browser do cliente não suportar, é um requisito do projeto e não uma obrigação comum a todos os aplicativos. Veja: se o cliente do projeto exige experiência Ajax, e aceita que em contrapartida o projeto exija determinado browser com JS ativado (e para muitos clientes isso é muito simples), por que eu vou gastar dinheiro oferecendo suporte a ambos os modelos (Ajax e não Ajax)?

Comment: Leia o primeiro parágrafo. Não seja tendencioso e ficar pinçando coisas soltas para achar problema onde não tem. Ler o texto todo é importante para não se passar por *troll*.

Comment: O primeiro parágrafo responde quando usar ou não Ajax, que é a resposta à pergunta. O segundo parágrafo fala outra coisa: fala que, quando usar, você deve garantir a experiência também no caso de Ajax não estar disponível; e que não fazer isso seria um erro. E é a isto que o meu comentário se refere.

Comment: Mas o primeiro parágrafo não pode ser ignorado. Se quiser não fazer isto, não faça, a experiência será limitada a navegadores que possuem esta capacidade. O segundo não invalida o primeiro. Eu só queria que você tivesse toda a disposição que tem para achar pelo em ovo em coisas que eu escrevo para achar problemas reais em outros *posts* pelo site. Tem várias coisas bem ruins para você se divertir. Não precisa ficar em cima das minhas coisas.

Comment: Eu não entendo suficientemente bem de Ajax para interpretar apropriadamente o que você quer dizer com "a tecnologia não estiver disponível". De todas as formas, do ponto de vista de UX, concordo essencialmente com a sua resposta. No cenário exemplificado, o usuário deveria ser avisado *previamente* no caso de alguma indisponibilidade para que não tenha o trabalho de preencher o longo formulário inutilmente (algo péssimo para a experiência).

Comment: Caso essa detecção prévia da indisponibilidade não seja possível, os dados devem ser mantidos de qualquer forma disponível (cookies, sessão, o que der). A ideia de fazer as questões serem respondidas uma a uma também é boa, porque dilui o trabalho percebido pelo usuário, e um erro com perda de dados se torna menos impactante.

Comment: @LuizVieira Em geral é possível detectar que um recurso está disponível. E dá até para resolver de outra forma quando ela não está disponível de forma transparente para o usuário. Melhorei e coloquei *link* para falar sobre isto. Quando eu respondi não tinha a *tag* UX e não sei se o AP queria isto, mas já que tem, fui mais por esse caminho.

Comment: @LuizVieira Basicamente todos os browsers suportam Ajax e apenas versões antigas, que possuem inclusive problemas de segurança e são pouco utilizadas, é que podem não possuir suporte. Eventualmente o cliente pode desativar a execução de JS e isso faria o Ajax e muitos outros recursos de usabilidade pararem de funcionar. JS hoje é relativamente seguro e desativá-lo é uma prática incomum. Uma *Single Page Application* usa JS e Ajax pesadamente, sendo algumas vezes quase 100% construída usando JS. Ou seja: em muitos cenários, garantir o funcionamento do App com **e** sem Ajax é altamente custoso.

Comment: @LuizVieira Já a verificação de que o JS foi desativado é bastante simples e barata - podemos dizer que "não custa nada" verificar se o browser é ponto fora da curva antes de deixar o usuário perder tempo; e, no caso de o JS ter sido desabilitado, avisar e interromper o funcionamento do app. Isto tem custo relativamente baixo (nada comparado a funcionar também sem JS/Ajax em aplicativos *rich client*).

Comment: @Caffé Bom, eu entrei por essa linha de raciocínio apenas porque a pergunta tem a tag UX (que, pelo que eu vi na revisão, foi você mesmo quem adicionou). Seja ou não custoso do ponto de vista de implementação, um problema de usabilidade/experiência que faz um usuário perder tudo o que digitou em um formulário longo é suficientemente grave a ponto de possivelmente custar o cliente. Então deve dar pra perceber que o problema vai além do JS ou do Ajax. Verificar desabilitação é uma ideia, mas pode impedir o serviço de ser utilizado (o que também não é necessariamente a melhor saída).

Comment: @Caffé Ou seja, essa pergunta tem aspectos relevantes tanto do ponto de vista de UX e do ponto de vista tecnológico (tal qual no mundo real). Talvez fosse interessante reduzir o foco dela retirando a tag UX, ou - se o AP tiver interesses mais abrangentes - abrir outras perguntas relacionadas.

Comment: @LuizVieira Achei boa idéia a Tag mas não me apego a ela; sem problemas remover. Meu ponto é: bloquear o uso do app ou suportar browser com e sem Ajax são decisões do projeto e nenhum dos dois modelos está incorreto. Na minha empresa temos Apps usados diariamente por mais de 200 mil pessoas **internamente** que exigem JS. Não haverá perda de cliente se o app bloquear browser com JS desativado. É apenas 1 de inúmeros exemplos de quando não é um erro deixar de gastar dinheiro garantindo dois modelos de funcionamento quando 1 deles pode nunca ser demandado. Por isso: decisão de projeto.

Answer (score 5):

A pergunta possui uma certa ambiguidade pois o título dá uma noção de se tratar de um tema mais amplo e genérico referente ao uso de ajax.

Todavia, o contexto traz um problema específico que é manter a salvo os dados que o usuário enviou mesmo que ocorra um erro e haja redirecionamentos.

Considerando o contexto, é possível manter os dados entrados pelo usuário em variáveis de sessão ou cookies.

Como exemplo, action="algumaurl.php".

Na página "algumaurl.php", que receberá os dados  (GET/POST), 
salve toda a informação recebida sem variáveis de sessão.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

/**
Inicia o uso de sessões.
*/
session_start();

/**
Os dados digitados pelo usuário serão salvos nessa sessão:
*/
$_SESSION['formulário_x'] = $_POST;

/**
Abaixo continua os seus scripts normalmente.
*/
```

Na página do formulário (pagina-2.php), adicione condicionais que verifiquem se há uma sessão presente.

Exemplo

```
<input type="text" name="nome_do_campo" value="<?php isset($_SESSION['formulário_x']['nome_do_campo']){echo $_SESSION['formulário_x']['nome_do_campo'];}?>">
```

Observação: Sempre que utilizar a variável global $_SESSION, deve iniciar as sessões com a função `session_start()`.

A função `session_start()` dispara cabeçalhos ao cliente, por isso, nunca deve ser invocada após um cabeçalho ser enviado. Quando isso ocorre, dispara erros do tipo "header already sent..".