# O que significa o termo Fallback?

Tags: terminologia

Eu já vi esse termo *fallback* sendo utilizado várias vezes. Inclusive, no *framework* que eu uso todo dia, o Laravel 5, essa palavra aparece numa determinada configuração:

Exemplo:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'pt_br',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Fallback Locale
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
| is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
| the language folders that are provided through your application.
|
*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

Pelo que pude entender no exemplo acima, essa palavra *fallback* está mais ou menos no sentido de: *"use essa localização, caso a outra não esteja disponível"*.

Isso é o que pude entender simplesmente analisando, mas dei uma pesquisada na internet afora e cheguei à conclusão de que o termo possa ser mais abrangente.

Então, gostaria de saber:

- O que significa termo *fallback* no nosso "mundo da programação"? Trata-se de um valor padrão caso um outro falhe, ou vai além disso?
- Essa palavra está relacionada com *rollback*?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Segundo a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallback) é uma opção de contingência, ou seja, algo é usado quando sua opção original não está disponível por alguma razão.

Essa é um definição genérica que serve bem à computação. Claro que em cada contexto pode ter um significado mais específico, mas sempre tem essa base. E ele é usado em contextos bem diversos (infraestrutura em geral, gerenciamento de projetos, desenvolvimento de software, configurações, algoritmos, estruturas de dados, testes, tecnologias específicas, etc.), alguns estão até em especificações de tecnologias.

A tradução é justamente [contingência ou plano B](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallback).

Não tem muito segredo, regras, nada. É só ter uma opção escolhida automaticamente quando a principal não está presente ou disponível por alguma razão. Note que a indisponibilidade pode ser momentânea ou mesmo selecionada por algum critério específico de acordo com a vontade de quem fez o software, provavelmente seguindo alguns requisitos.

Isso é diferente de ter uma opção *default* onde você tem algo escolhido e só se for explicitamente escolhido outro é que troca a opção. O *fallback* ocorre automaticamente e o substantivo é o oposto do *default*, é o que não é o padrão.

## Exemplos

Um exemplo é um ambiente de execução que tenta usar uma opção nativa, não tendo disponível ela tenta emular a execução (renderização de algo, compilação, etc.).

Há casos que o termo pode ser usado para opções de reserva, como um banco de dados que entra em ação quando outro falha, mas esse uso é menos comum, e muitas vezes o termo usado é *backup*.

Fala-se muito em *fallback* quando se usa tecnologias web onde um mecanismo pode não estar disponível em um navegador. Tem até [marcação para indicar a contingência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style/fallback).

Mas pode ser estendido para qualquer tecnologia. Tem uso quando várias versões estão disponíveis e uma delas é a preferida, mas outras podem atender também.

Nem vou citar exemplos de hardware, redes, etc. porque não é nosso foco, mas é onde ocorre com muita frequência para dar mais confiabilidade.

## Rollback

A única relação é que as duas terminam com *back*. Esse termo é a ação de voltar para trás, desfazer o que foi feito e voltar ao estado original. Em geral por causa de uma falha, mas pode ser só por opção.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 15):

***Fallback*** (*contingência*, em tradução livre) é uma opção a ser utilizada caso a opção preferida não esteja disponível.

O papel do *fallback* é de aumentar a confiabilidade e disponibilidade de sistemas.

Em se tratando de software, é um esquema de estruturação que permite o tratamento de erros de programa, dados ou processo. Geralmente (porém não exlusivamente) envolve restauração de dados, de estado ou continuação de execução. Alguns exemplos práticos:

- [Renderização de gráficos 3D via software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rendering) se o computador não possui aceleradora de vídeo, placa gráfica ou [biblioteca-alvo](https://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch04s03.html)
- [O sistema de contingência de APIs do ambiente Android](https://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html) (aplicações escritas para APIs modernas conseguem ser executadas em dispositivos mais antigos)

Por outro lado, ***Rollback*** (ou *restauração*) é uma das possíveis ações a serem tomadas no caso de um erro fatal de ambiente, dado ou estado. Significa a restauração do estado da sua aplicação para um anterior, mais estável e funcional.

Answer (score 11):

Fallback significa "plano B" ou plano de emergência, ou seja se a configuração definida pelo programador falhar ainda vai existir uma opção padrão que assumirá um valor válido.

Não tem nenhuma correspondência com o termo rollback.

Answer (score 6):

A própria descrição em inglês responde.

> | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current
>   one  | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any
>   of  | the language folders that are provided through your application.

Conforme descrito, pode acontecer de uma setagem personalizada não ser possível, então, "cai de volta" (fallback) para a setagem padrão.

Um exemplo, quando tentar obter o idioma do browser do usuário e porventura não conseguir obter o valor, é feito um fallback para a setagem padrão.

Answer (score 4):

***Fallback*** especifica qual arquivo usar se tentar acessar um arquivo que não esteja armazenado.

*Fallback* é diferente de *Rollback*.

- *Rollback* é um termo usado no sentido de restaurar dados a uma condição que foi previamente salva, como um restore de um backup.
- *Fallback* já é algo mais abrangente, pois é um termo usado para designar o planejamento com os procedimentos necessários para restaurar um sistema de volta a condição operacional.

Answer (score 4):

*Fallback* não é, de maneira geral, um termo técnico em informática. É utilizado de acordo com seu significado geral, de "contingência" ou "alternativa secundária".

*Rollback* é um termo técnico bem estabelecido, especialmente em banco de dados, quando se tem uma *transaçao* e no final é feito o *commit* ou o *rollback*.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo mais simples é quando definimos um valor para algum campo, no seu site por exemplo, vindo de uma API e caso não exista, você pode definir um padrão.
É bem recorrente o termo fallback e o uso na programação.