# Verificar se um email existe ou o seu domínio e-mail

Tags: java, validação, email

Estou precisando verificar em Java se um e-mail ou se seu domínio existe. Não me refiro a tratar a validade do e-mail, usando por exemplo expressão regular, mas sim realmente verificar se existe uma conta associada. Vi alguns fóruns na web porém muitos desatualizados de 2014 para trás, como eu consigo fazer isso hoje.

**Exemplo:** zedascouves123@gmail.com

Quero ser capaz de verificar pelo e-mail completo `zedascouves123@gmail.com`, e/ou pelo domínio `@gmail.com`, o que for mais viável e possível de implementar.

Seria algo parecido com o que [esse site](https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/) faz.

Comment: O google api-client-library, tem um metodo HTTP Request watch, POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/watch aonde o userId é o email. Caso esse e-mail seja invalido retornar uma mensagem de erro.

Veja no link: 

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch?hl=pt-BR

Comment: A única maneira de verificar se um email existe (ou se existe ao menos um alias) é mandando o email e verificando se teve sucesso (preferencialmente com um link de confirmação). O resto é chute.

Comment: A não ser que você fosse a Google, por exemplo, que tem outros meios de saber isso (provavelmente o endereço de quase todas pessoas já passou pelos servidores deles inúmeras vezes). De qualquer forma, entre saber e liberar uma API para isso tem um abismo ético.

Answer (score 7):

Visto que nem toda API de email tem suporte a verificação de existência de um dado email, é provavel que não haja forma de verificar isto programaticamente. Alguns blogs sugerem usar [telnet com o suposto email](https://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/) e verificar se você recebe uma resposta 550. Isso não garante que o usuário tem acesso ao email, além de ser bem complexo de fazer programaticamente. Como dito em [outra resposta a esta pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/566121/3846065), você pode mandar requisições VRFY, que não é implementada em todo servidor, ou uma requisição RCPT, que pode ser silenciosamente descartada e não garante a validade todas as vezes.

A implementação mais comum é a verificação em duas etapas de email, isto é, você manda um email com um link de confirmação(que é acompanhado de algum token de verificação), e o usuário clica no link para confirmar que o email é tanto válido quanto dele.

Comment: O problema que to encontrando é esse, que nem todos os métodos são garantidos. O problema é que a validação de email em duas etapas não encaixa no meu cenário, pois a validação não é realizada quando o usuário se cadastra. Queria algo igual a esse site aqui: https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/

Comment: Esta é a única resposta válida hoje. Sem a verificação em duas etapas, nada garante que um email existe. Inclusive, testei a ferramenta indicada no link, e o máximo que ela informa dos meus domínios é que não dá para verificar.

Comment: Entendo a complexidade. E a segunda verificação que informei? Verificar se o domínio é válido? "gmail.com", "yahoo.com", "hotmail.com". Esse teria uma forma de eu verificar?

Comment: @Pedro aí é questão de fazer uma requisição DNS, em princípio, e testar se existe algum MX ou se o A ou AAAA possuem SMTP.

Comment: @Bacco foi isso que fiz aqui, utilizei a classe InetAdress do "java.net". Consegui aqui resolver meu problema.

Answer (score 5):

Pra mim, verificar se um e-mail existe só serve para enviar *spam*. Por isso não me importa como solucionar esta questão. Nem quero saber se tem o endereço da caixa postal ou o domínio.

Verificar se alguém que está se cadastrando em algum lugar e tem um e-mail válido (em todos os sentidos), inclusive se é dele, só tem duas soluções.

A primeira já foi citada a outra resposta, por isso já votei nela, tem que mandar uma mensagem para o usuário onde ele confirma que recebeu. É falho, mas não tem muito o que fazer. Na verdade funciona em quase todos os casos se a UX for boa.

A outra é fazer direito, ou seja, não peça para a pessoa se cadastrar, peça para ela se autenticar. Use os dados dele exigindo menos esforço que fazer um cadastro e sabe que não só o e-mail existe, mas ele é de quem está se cadastrando, sem nenhuma outra interação além do acesso imediato à página de autorização do autenticador escolhido.

Pode ser a [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login), [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e muito outros, até mesmo alguns de nicho, como [este site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Procure por [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) ([lista de provedores internacionais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OAuth_providers)), [Single Sign On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), [User-Managed Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Managed_Access), [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), [OATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initiative_for_Open_Authentication), só para ficar em alguns.

Nenhum é panaceia. Utilize um [*fallback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152503/101) se o usuário não puder usar um fornecedor desses, aí confirme mandando um *token* para ele se autenticar, a primeira solução.

Se nada disso resolver, senta e chora :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se pudesse de um segundo voto, eu daria só pelo último parágrafo

Comment: Eu entendo essa questão, solucionei o caso de outra forma, fazendo requisição ao DNS informado após o "@", com isso já consigo resolver meu problema. Entendo que o melhor passo seria a verificação a partir da confirmação de email do usuário, porém no meu caso isso não se aplica, pois não faço essa validação no processo de cadastro do usuário.