# Podemos desenvolver uma aplicação web 100% JavaScript/HTML/CSS sem backend?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, back-end

Sou desenvolvedor *backend* Java e sempre usei JavaScript no *frontend* com a finalidade de dar dinamismo e melhor interação as páginas HTML (sempre desenvolvi sistemas corporativos).

Há como desenvolver um sistema corporativo 100% em JavaScript/HTML/CSS? Onde ficariam as regras e objetos do negócio (o *model* no MVC)? Teria que obrigatoriamente usar Node.js no *backend*?

Comment: Esses frameworks e bibliotecas que você citou são todos de frontend. Se seus fronts já são em html/css/js, continuarão sendo. O backend pode usar qualquer coisa, se não for obrigatório usar js. E fica responsável pela persistência dos dados e geralmente boa parte das regras de negócio.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, parece que você acredita que só tem um jeito de fazer as coisas, que tem que ter MVC.

Você pode fazer o que quiser do jeito que quiser. É claro que algumas coisas são mais adequadas que outras para certos cenários e alguma opções podem dar trabalho demais, oferecer menos do que se espera ou exigir o que não pode ser ofertado.

Você pode fazer um jogo, uma aplicação de uso individual que não precisa contato com servidor. Mas eu faria essas aplicações nativas (desktop/mobile), tem quem prefere web para tudo. O usuário vai ter uma experiência sofrível na maioria das vezes para nenhum ganho importante.

Tem como ter um cliente baseado em [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) para dispensar o navegador, mas não gosto dos resultados em grande parte dos casos.

É possível até mesmo fazer uma rede de comunicação entre vários clientes, mas não acho que compense.

Tem diversos motivos para ter um servidor e não confiar no cliente.

Se precisa mesmo de um servidor, e aplicações corporativas costumam precisar de um, então a única opção popular é usar o Node.js (agora tem o [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/444449/101)). Tem outras implementações, mas nenhuma que eu possa falar, duvido que alguma seja útil a não ser em nicho específico.

Claro que precisará de um servidor de banco de dados também. Possivelmente outras coisas, incluindo um servidor HTTP.

Se o Node é a melhor opção para o problema, pode usá-lo. Se o motivo de escolhê-lo é porque só sabe JavaScript, aí o motivo da escolha é errado.

Pelo que eu entendo, na maioria das vezes, se o Node/Deno atende bem, MVC é canhão para matar passarinho. Mas pode estar mudando um pouco.

Pode existir, mas nunca vi um sistema corporativo bom escrito com tecnologias web, no máximo usar HTTP para comunicação como [*fallback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152503/101) quando não tem outra opção. Na verdade isso vale para qualquer aplicação rodando no navegador. Salvam-se algumas aplicações usando o [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) ou um concorrente dele. Mas dá para fazer melhor nativo.

Claro que nem todo mundo exige algo bom, caso contrário não teria tanta gente usando algo assim. Uma dica, faço sistemas desde os anos 80 e naquela época os usuários eram muito mais produtivos.

Mas possível é, e tem muita gente fazendo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não tenho nada em mente para fazer, só estou estudando e fiquei na dúvida aonde colocar regras de negócio e objetos de negócio em um modelo de desenvolvimento usando JavaScript/HTML/CSS. Sei que existem diversas soluções para um mesmo problema. Só usei o MVC como um forma de ilustrar a minha dúvida. Sendo mais hardcode... tendo uma regra do tipo: se o saldo é maior que X faça isso. Aonde essa regra fica em um sistema 100% JavaScript/HTML/CSS?

Comment: Se vai ter servidor é igual ao que faz no Java, claro que cada *framework* é diferente. Se não vai ter servidor não vejo muita vantagem em ter um sistema cerimonioso, então o mais simples possível é melhor. Curiosamente a maior vantagem do MVC praticamente não é usada