# Deno e Node.js - Compatibilidade

Tags: node.js, deno

O criador do Node.js desenvolveu uma nova plataforma de JavaScript chamada [**Deno**](https://deno.land/).

Os códigos escritos para Node.js serão compatíveis com essa nova plataforma?

[Existe uma *issue* aberta sobre isso](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2644), mas não compreendi bem em que pé isso está.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não há compatibilidade total e não é possível tê-la. O produto tem diferenças fundamentais e não foi feito para compatibilidade. O que eu entendi ali é que eles querem algumas facilidades e ferramentas que ajudem mudar do Node para o Deno.

Há algum progresso para facilitar. Tem casos que as pessoas que fizeram bibliotecas estão mudando para que funcione com o Deno já que a API é diferente. Seu código pode sofrer também mesmo não usando essas bibliotecas, mas não será trágico. Isso será o que mais trará problemas, principalmente pela forma de usar os módulos.

Note que não estou falando que incompatibilidades temporárias e acidentais não devam ser consertadas. Só tenha certo que a API é parecida, mas não 100% igual. Você terá que tentar e ver se dá muito problema com seu código.

Qualquer coisa de baixo nível feito para Node não funcionará porque o Deno é escrito em Rust com um código todo novo.

Todo sistema de *build* é diferente, sempre é em soluções diferentes. Quem tinha *builds* simples não sofrerão muito, mas como era possível fazer algo simples com Node e ser útil?

Embora qualquer código em JavaScript vá funcionar nele porque TypeScript entende qualquer código JavaScript a linguagem oficial dele é TS, portanto se você não começa mudar seu código para TS não terá todas vantagens do Deno. Algumas pessoas já usavam TS mas faziam uma conversão antes, agora é "nativo".

Por segurança algumas coisas que antes era permitida não é mais (se você desativar essa proteção começa perder vantagens de ter ido para o Deno).

Não há tantas mudanças assim e não acho que a compatibilidade deva ser uma meta. Quem quer ir para o Deno deve saber que será diferente e se tem um legado deve pagar um preço para mudar, e ter ganhos depois. Quem não pode pagar por isso ficará em uma tecnologia que claramente é inferior e tomara que morra de inanição :).

Tem uma série de padrões que podem não funcionar mais porque pressupõem coisas que o Deno é diferente. Não é uma incompatibilidade direta, mas pode não funcionar se ele se valia de um detalhe de implementação que não existe mais (poderia deixar de existir até no Node).

Lá está dizendo algo sobre a maturidade do Deno. As pessoas já estão usando, mas nada garante que tudo esteja perfeito, está próximo.

Pelo que entendi a comunidade criará alguns facilitadores para rodar coisas do Node no Deno.

## Conclusão

Para quem aprendeu só seguindo receitas de bolo será sofrido. Mas eu acredito que a comunidade começará criar receitas para fazer a transição mais facilmente.

Foi desenvolvido um produto novo e não só uma versão nova porque só dava para consertar os erros quebrando a compatibilidade.

Eu sei que isso atrairá gente que não gosta da resposta mas o Node sempre foi um erro. Eu não sei o quanto é melhor, mas o Deno é um passo importante quando a pessoa optar por isso pelos motivos certos. Ainda bem que o criador do Node não foi orgulhoso como acontece muito na nossa área e preferiu criar algo que potencialmente mataria seu produto original.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).