# Pular linha em uma função com implementação

Tags: javascript, funções, quebras-de-linha

Criei uma função `pularLinha()` para não precisar ficar repetindo `<br>` constantemente, contudo para fazer a linha pular mais de uma vez dentro da função `mostra()`, eu chamo `pularLinha()` por duas vezes.

Ai penso e se fosse necessário pular de 5 em 5 linhas, chamaria a mesma função por 5 vezes dentro da função `mostra()`? Isso ficaria horrível!

Tentei colocar uma implementação para melhorar o código e ficar funcional, mas não consegui.

```
    let pulaLinha = function (){
        document.write("<br>");
    };

    let mostra = function(frase){
        document.write(frase);
        pulaLinha(); pulaLinha();

    }

    let ano = 2012; 
    mostra("Eu nasci em : " + (ano - 25)); 
    mostra("Adriano nasceu em : " + (ano - 26));
    mostra("Paulo nasceu em : " + (ano - 32));
```

Comment: Se precisa repetir várias vezes a mesma coisa, [use um `for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). Outro detalhe, para declarar funções, faça simplesmente `function mostra(frase) { etc}`. Nesse caso não há vantagem nenhuma em fazer `mostra = function(etc..)`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/112052 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/33040926

Comment: Outra coisa que acho que está errada aí é que fica dando um **document.write** em cima de outro, document.write sobrescreve todo html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos arrumar esse abuso de *lambda* onde uma função normal funciona melhor. Se alguém ensinou assim, fuja.

Eu não acho horrível um código mostrar que faz exatamente o que é intenção dele. Se ele deve pular duas linhas então chame o código que faz o que deseja duas vezes. Se quer 5 vezes faça isso, embora eu acho exagero usar 5 vezes. Mas se realmente precisa e são muitas vezes (não faça para 2) então é só fazer um laço.

```js
function pulaLinha() {
    document.write("<br>");
};

function mostra(frase) {
    document.write(frase);
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) pulaLinha();
}

let ano = 2012; 
mostra("Eu nasci em : " + (ano - 25)); 
mostra("Adriano nasceu em : " + (ano - 26));
mostra("Paulo nasceu em : " + (ano - 32));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/Parameter.js).

Acho um enorme exagero, mas se quiser pode parametrizar a função que pula linha com um número de repetição:

```js
function pulaLinha(repeticao = 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < repeticao; i++) document.write("<br>");
};

function mostra(frase) {
    document.write(frase);
    pulaLinha(2);
}

let ano = 2012; 
mostra("Eu nasci em : " + (ano - 25)); 
mostra("Adriano nasceu em : " + (ano - 26));
mostra("Paulo nasceu em : " + (ano - 32));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Repetition.js).

Só lembrando que o `let` e o argumento *default* funciona em interpretadores modernos, então se usará em Node, [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/444449/101) ou coisas semelhantes ou pode garantir que rodará em navegador moderno ou usará um transpilador para EcmaScipt mais antigo, então pode usar, se não vá de `var`.

Comment: +1 pelo *"arrumar esse abuso de lambda"*, nada como um bom codigo vanilla, fácil de entender :)