# Importando pacotes públicos no Deno

Tags: importação, deno

Eu estava vendo um exemplos de código no [Deno](https://deno.land/), e algo me chamou atenção e me gerou um certo desconforto. Foi o modo como os pacotes públicos são importados pelo Deno, através de uma URL.

Eu sei que o `npm` não é o mundo perfeito e tem lá seus problemas, mas usar este modo de importar módulos através de uma URL me gerou uma certa estranheza ao olhar pela primeira vez. Eu sei que a linguagem Golang faz importação dessa maneira, mas como nunca usei essa linguagem, não tenho o que comentar. Mas trazer isso para um ambiente "semelhante" ao NodeJS, por assim, dizer, me deixou com algumas dúvidas ao olhar um código assim:

```js
import { Response } from "https://deno.land/std@0.53.0/http/server.ts";
```

- Tenho que importar por uma URL em todos os meus arquivos que eu precisar de uma biblioteca/framework/módulo?
- Se um desses módulos sofrer uma atualização de segurança, ou ficar *deprecated*, ou se os repositórios mudarem de domínio, ou simplesmente ficarem fora do ar, eu tenho que "varrer" manualmente cada um deles e mudar na mão essas versões?
- Deno usa um sistema de cache embutido para que você não precise baixar um monte de coisas (que você já baixou para seus outros projetos), mas cada projeto tem suas versões de pacotes, como gerenciar isso? Tem como gerenciar esse cache?

Eu cheguei a olhar na documentação que eles permitem voce criar um arquivo `import_map.json` ([ver aqui](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/import_maps)), onde você coloca todos os *imports* dentro de um arquivo e dispense fazer importação manual nos seus arquivos.

- Mas e aí? Se eu tiver 50 *imports* nesse JSON, vou ter que gerenciar manualmente do mesmo jeito?
- Se eu atualizar esse JSON, ele irá sobreescrever a versão anterior salva no cache?

Enfim, não sei se eu estou reclamando cedo demais e futuramente haverá um gerenciador de pacotes (não sei se essa ideia está em pauta para o Deno).

Apesar de o Deno ter idéias bem interessantes, principalmente relacionado a segurança e poder rodar TypeScript sem precisar instalar nada, me chamou bastante atenção, mas pelo pouco que estudei sobre, cheguei a conclusão que o Deno tem muito que caminhar e evoluir para chegar onde o NodeJS chegou, pois no momento os unicos propósitos do Deno, ao meu ver, foi gerar notícia, pois não vejo propósito para usar em produção, pelo menos por enquanto, e estudar seus conceitos que diferem do NodeJS.

Mas cabe a discussão do porque essa plataforma já não veio com um gerenciador de pacote nativo. Talvez eu esteja falando besteira e daqui a uns anos essa pergunta seja irrelevante.
Aceito qualquer material sobre o assunto como resposta e ficam aqui as minhas dúvidas.

Comment: "Mas e ai? Se eu tiver 50 imports nesse JSON, vou ter que gerenciar manualmente do mesmo jeito?" - não entendi, não é o mesmo conceito do `package.json`, atualizando em um só lugar?

Comment: @RafaelTavares de certa forma é, mas seria algo de mudar a url de ´*/std@0.53.0/http/server.ts´ para ´*/std@0.60.0/http/server.ts´  e se isso não iria sobreescrever os arquivos que já estão no chache.

Comment: Essa atualização deveria ser colocada em outra pergunta e não ai, você não pode responder na própria pergunta uma duvida ou sugestão.

Comment: @novic ah sim, eu ia colocar ela com uma resposta, mas acabei esquecendo. Obrigado por lembrar :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>**Atenção**, esta resposta contém opiniões.</sup>

---

Instalei o Deno esses dias (versão 1.5) para "brincar" um pouco, então vou colocar minhas impressões, que podem ajudar com suas dúvidas. Um detalhe é que comecei a mexer com Node há cerca de 2 anos e não me considero um *expert* nesta tecnologia (ou seja, ainda não mexi o suficiente para ter uma opinião consolidada, apenas impressões de quem ainda não conhece a fundo).

> *Tenho que importar por uma URL em todos os meus arquivos que eu precisar de uma biblioteca/framework/módulo?*

A princípio, se forem libs externas, sim (vale lembrar que você também pode importar módulos locais do próprio *file system*). Claro que o `import_map.json` que você mencionou é uma alternativa para "digitar menos", mas me parece que a ideia é essa mesmo (entendi que ele seria mais ou menos - mas não exatamente - como um "`package.json` com URL's").

É totalmente diferente do Node, no qual há um repositório central de onde tudo é baixado "magicamente", assim você não precisa explicitar qual URL será usada - embora [seja possível usar mais de um *registry*](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user). Talvez o Deno seja assim porque ainda não há um repositório central (teremos? não sei), ou talvez porque a ideia seja essa mesmo: a de possibilitar que você baixe de qualquer lugar, sem se limitar a uma única "entidade central" que contém todos os pacotes do mundo.

Ambas as abordagens (centralizado x descentralizado) possuem vantagens e desvantagens, e cada um vai preferir uma delas por vários motivos. <sup><sub>Sinceramente, para mim não importa muito se é centralizado ou não, bastaria que as pessoas não abusassem das dependências, [e não adicionassem módulos desnecessários para coisas triviais](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/886zji/why_has_there_been_nearly_3_million_installs_of/), mas divago...</sub></sup>

De qualquer forma, não tem modelo perfeito. Um repositório centralizado pode facilitar o gerenciamento (menos URL's para configurar), mas não necessariamente garante "qualidade"/curadoria (convenhamos, tem [muita](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-odd) [coisa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-even) [questionável](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-not-odd) no npm). Mas um modelo descentralizado também não garante isso, <speculation>embora a "concorrência" possa talvez estimular uma busca pela qualidade</speculation>. Acho até que podia ter alguma abstração acima do `import_map.json`, talvez se tivesse "perfis/grupos de URL's preferidas" ou algo assim. Mas talvez o Deno queira começar simples e só depois ir complicando (se for feito com cuidado, não vai virar a bagunça que muitos softwares acabam virando). Não sei, só o tempo dirá.

Enfim, o Deno está sendo feito com ideias diferentes do Node, e ainda não dá pra cravar se ele vai "acertar" ou "errar". Mas pelo menos está tentando fazer algo diferente, o que é louvável (dado que ambos foram criados pela [mesma pessoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Dahl), e é incomum na nossa área alguém que resolve fazer algo que pode matar sua criação anterior, mesmo com esta ainda sendo popular). Eu prefiro não dar o veredito sobre o que é melhor, até porque não acho que tem "melhor", o que tem são prós e contras de cada abordagem, e cada um escolhe o que preferir (de preferência, com base em avaliação técnica). Em computação tudo é *trade-off* <sup><sub>*o que não pode é virar "guerrinha religiosa"*</sub></sup>.

---

> *Se um desses módulos sofrer uma atualização de segurança, ou ficar 'deprecated', ou se os repositórios mudarem de domínio, ou simplesmente ficarem fora do ar, eu tenho que 'varrer' manualmente cada um deles e mudar na mão essas versões?*

Sim.

Mas isso também não acontece com qualquer gerenciador de dependências? Se você está usando uma lib qualquer e ela é atualizada ou removida, vai ter que ir lá no arquivo de configuração (seja ele qual for) e mudar na mão. Claro que é possível você configurar o `package.json` de forma que [ele use versões mais novas automaticamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808), mas isso não te livra dos [problemas que podem ocorrer se uma lib for removida de repente](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/).

Claro que com cada lib vinda de uma URL diferente, pode ser que dê um pouco mais de trabalho para gerenciar. Mas pode ser que alguém crie alguma solução para isso. Veremos...

---

> *Se eu atualizar esse JSON, ele irá sobreescrever a versão anterior salva no cache?*

Não.

Para testar isso, criei uma lib bem simples, com 2 versões, e coloquei na seguinte estrutura:

```
libs/
  |  
   \_ mylib@1.0
  |      |
  |       \_ mylib.ts
  |
   \_ mylib@2.0
         |
          \_ mylib.ts
```

O conteúdo é o mais simples possível:

- `mylib@1.0/mylib.ts`:

```ts
export function f() {
    console.log('mylib 1.0');
}
```

- `mylib@2.0/mylib.ts`:

```ts
export function f() {
    console.log('mylib 2.0');
}
```

E fiz um arquivo de teste (`test.ts`):

```ts
import { f } from "http://localhost:1234/libs/mylib@1.0/mylib.ts";

f();
```

<sub>Repare que deixei as libs rodando em um HTTP server local.</sub>

Ao rodá-lo (`deno run test.ts`) na primeira vez, a lib é baixada (a versão 1.0) e a saída é:

```
Download http://localhost:1234/libs/mylib@1.0/mylib.ts
Check file:///home/hkotsubo/test_deno/test.ts
mylib 1.0
```

Da segunda vez em diante, o download não é mais feito (confirmei isso também vendo os logs do HTTP server, e fiz outro teste com o HTTP server desligado e funcionou), e a saída do script é apenas "mylib 1.0".

E no diretório de cache, foi criada uma entrada para `mylib`, na pasta `.cache/deno/deps/http/localhost_PORT1234` (a pasta `.cache` foi criada na home do meu usuário), com 2 arquivos:

```
fd82babb7ac771cf78249676f381f5aa11a8eb6e7199a09893615123f2ec587f
fd82babb7ac771cf78249676f381f5aa11a8eb6e7199a09893615123f2ec587f.metadata.json
```

O primeiro contém todo o conteúdo da versão 1.0 de `mylib.ts`, e o segundo contém metadados do mesmo:

```js
{
  "headers": {
    "date": "Wed, 28 Oct 2020 10:51:30 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "55",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "host": "localhost:1234"
  },
  "url": "http://localhost:1234/libs/mylib@1.0/mylib.ts"
}
```

Agora o que acontece se eu mudar meu script para usar a versão 2.0 de `mylib.ts`?

```ts
// test.ts, usar a versão 2.0 de mylib
import { f } from "http://localhost:1234/libs/mylib@2.0/mylib.ts";

f();
```

Ao rodar novamente com `deno run test.ts`, a saída é:

```
Download http://localhost:1234/libs/mylib@2.0/mylib.ts
Check file:///home/hkotsubo/test_deno/test.ts
mylib 2.0
```

Ele fez outro download (afinal, é outra versão, outra URL), mas novamente isso só é feito na primeira vez que rodo o script. Da segunda vez em diante, o download não é mais feito e o código só imprime "mylib 2.0". E no diretório de cache foram criados mais 2 arquivos, ou seja, agora são 4:

```
fd82babb7ac771cf78249676f381f5aa11a8eb6e7199a09893615123f2ec587f
fd82babb7ac771cf78249676f381f5aa11a8eb6e7199a09893615123f2ec587f.metadata.json
fb378398f20710b3d0dc83428cddc811c69646561a7da4fd6d3ec2989be2756b
fb378398f20710b3d0dc83428cddc811c69646561a7da4fd6d3ec2989be2756b.metadata.json
```

Os 2 arquivos novos referem-se à versão 2.0 de `mylib.ts`: o primeiro contém o código, e o segundo (de metadados) contém informações da respectiva versão:

```js
{
  "headers": {
    "host": "localhost:1234",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "55",
    "date": "Wed, 28 Oct 2020 11:02:34 GMT"
  },
  "url": "http://localhost:1234/libs/mylib@2.0/mylib.ts"
}
```

Repare como a URL é diferente do outro arquivo.

Ou seja, ambas as versões de `mylib.ts` ficam no cache, e eu posso mudar o `import` usado em `test.ts` para usar qualquer uma delas, que a mesma é encontrada no cache corretamente (e nenhum download é feito novamente). Não há confusão entre as versões.

Lembre-se que o cache é centralizado e **externo** ao seu projeto. Todos os projetos irão procurar no mesmo cache, e como ele consegue manter várias versões da mesma lib, não tem risco de sobrescrever nada (cada projeto pode usar a versão que quiser, que esta é lida do cache sem problemas).

> **Atenção, parágrafo com opinião pessoal:** eu acho que é melhor assim, com um cache centralizado que só baixa uma única vez, em vez de ter um diretório (`node_modules`) para cada projeto, em que as mesmas coisas podem ser baixadas várias e várias vezes, o que muitas vezes é redundante, já que se tratam das mesmas versões das mesmas libs (a propósito, ter um cache centralizado também é a abordagem que outros gerenciadores, como o Maven e Gradle por exemplo, já usavam há muito tempo). Mas não vamos entrar em uma discussão interminável sobre qual gerenciador de dependências é melhor, para não perder o foco da resposta. Até porque, como já disse, não tem solução perfeita, cada abordagem tem seus prós e contras.
>
> Só deixo para reflexão uma apresentação do criador do Node, em especial o que ele diz [a partir dos 13 minutos deste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3BM9TB-8yA#t=13m) ("*It's my fault and I'm very sorry*"). Talvez seja por isso que ele quis fazer o Deno tão diferente do Node, e [provavelmente "nunca" haverá 100% de compatilibidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444460/112052).

Apenas para complementar, a partir da versão 1.28 o Deno [passou a suportar *npm specifiers*](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.2/node/npm_specifiers) no lugar da URL (antes, "funcionava" se rodasse com a *flag* `--unstable`, mas agora o suporte, segundo a documentação, está estável).

Ou seja, além da URL, você também pode fazer algo como:

```js
// usar npm specifier em vez de URL
import moment from "npm:moment@2.29.4";

// usar normalmente
console.log(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Porém, ao contrário do Node, ele não cria um diretório `node_modules` para cada projeto (a menos que se use a opção `--node-modules-dir`, mas o *default* é não criá-lo). Em vez disso, ele continua guardando os pacotes no cache (no caso, ele criou uma pasta `.cache/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/moment`), e ele baixa apenas uma vez: rodando o código acima, ele só baixou na primeira vez em que rodei. Mesmo criando outro script em outra pasta com o mesmo código (ou seja, usando a mesma versão da mesma lib), ele não baixou novamente.

Ou seja, continua funcionando de maneira similar, a diferença é que em vez de uma URL explícita, ele busca no *registry* do npm, de acordo com o *specifier* indicado.

---

> *mesmo sem passar a flag --allow-net, ele acessou a internet e baixou os pacotes*

Faz sentido. Se uma das premissas do Deno é que você pode importar módulos diretamente de uma URL, então por padrão o `import` tem que acessar a internet.

A [opção `--allow-net`](https://deno.land/manual@v1.5.0/getting_started/permissions) serve para que o **código do script** tenha acesso à rede. Vejamos o [script de exemplo que tem no site do Deno](https://deno.land/#getting-started):

```ts
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/http/server.ts";
const s = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");
for await (const req of s) {
  req.respond({ body: "Hello World\n" });
}
```

Eu salvei este código no arquivo `server.ts` e rodei (`deno run server.ts`). A saída foi:

```
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/http/server.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/_util/assert.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/encoding/utf8.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/io/bufio.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/async/mod.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/http/_io.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/http/http_status.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/textproto/mod.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/async/delay.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/async/mux_async_iterator.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/async/deferred.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/async/pool.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/bytes/mod.ts
Check file:///home/hkotsubo/test_deno/server.ts
error: Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access to "0.0.0.0:8000", run again with the --allow-net flag
    at processResponse (core.js:226:13)
    at Object.jsonOpSync (core.js:250:12)
    at opListen (deno:cli/rt/30_net.js:32:17)
    at Object.listen (deno:cli/rt/30_net.js:207:17)
    at serve (server.ts:287:25)
    at server.ts:2:11
```

Ou seja, o `import` baixou as dependências, mas o código do script (que sobe um HTTP server) não rodou porque precisa da *flag* `--allow-net`.

Se o `--allow-net` fosse necessário para importar os pacotes, então todos os scripts que tivessem algum `import` (mesmo aqueles cujo código não faz nenhum acesso à rede) teriam que rodar com esta *flag* habilitada, o que não faria sentido nenhum (se todo mundo precisasse desta permissão, uma *flag* para habilitar isso seria meio inútil, seria mais fácil que ela já estivesse habilitada por padrão). Por isso que o `import` já consegue acessar a internet por *default* (ou seja, pra mim faz todo sentido que seja assim).

---

> *não sei se eu estou reclamando cedo demais e futuramente haverá um gerenciador de pacotes*

Não pesquisei a fundo, mas em uma busca rápida encontrei [isso](https://github.com/crewdevio/Trex) ("*package management tool for deno similar to npm but keeping close to the deno philosophy*"). Provavelmente já devem ter surgido muitas outras alternativas, e só o tempo dirá qual delas irá se tornar mais popular.

Só pra constar, na [documentação](https://deno.land/manual) é dito que "*Deno explicitly takes on the role of both runtime and package manager*" - ou seja, o Deno se considera um "gerenciador de pacotes". Talvez não da mesma forma que o Node faz (e que todos já se acostumaram), mas enfim...

A conclusão que chego é que ainda é cedo para afirmar se o Deno será um sucesso ou não. São apenas 2 anos de existência contra mais de 10 anos do Node, e ainda não sabemos o que surgirá (se alguém vai criar um gerenciador de dependências "matador", ou se inventarão alguma outra coisa, etc), não dá pra saber como vão estar as coisas daqui a 10 anos. Pode ser que apenas um deles sobreviva, pode ser que ambos coexistam, pode ser que surja outra coisa e mate ambos. Não tem como saber...

<sup>*Então eu acho que sim, você está reclamando cedo demais :-)*</sup>

Comment: Sei que comentar só pra elogiar é um _anti-pattern_ por aqui, mas a resposta ficou excelente. :)

Comment: Excelente explicacao/opniao sobre o Deno. Eu comecei a estudar o NodeJS pouco mais de 1 ano e meio, entao eu meio que me doutrinei com os conceitos que o Node implementou e meio que passei a achar que o criador do Node iria replicar estes conceitos no Deno. Concordo quando voce diz que nao existe melhor nem pior, ate porque querer comparar 10 anos de Node com o Deno, que nasceu recentemente, seria besteira da minha parte. Mas meu intuito nao era falar mal do Deno ou ser fanboy do Node, mas sim questionar e trocar ideias.

Comment: `o que não pode é virar "guerrinha religiosa"`. Concordo 100%. Eu voltei a ler a documentacao do Deno, como hobby e curiosidade, e como bom nerd que sou, estou aberto para aprender coisas novas, entao o Deno foi, digamos, minha "segunda ling. de backend", estou gostando de alguns conceitos, questiono outros, mas me agrada ver algo novo. `Então eu acho que sim, você está reclamando cedo demais :-)` hahaha, eu tambem acho. Depois de alguns meses desde a pergunta, acho que me cedo apressei demais. Deno tem um longo caminho pela frente. Daqui a dois anos vou voltar nessa pergunta e achar graca XD

Answer (score 2):

## ATUALIZAÇÃO (26/10/2020)

Voltei a ler a documentação inteira do Deno, e algumas dúvidas estão começando a serem resolvidas. Irei fazer atualizações caso ajude outras pessoas.

Para esta dúvida:

> Deno usa um sistema de cache embutido para que você não precise baixar um monte de coisas (que você já baixou para seus outros projetos), mas cada projeto tem suas versões de pacotes, como gerenciar isso? Tem como gerenciar esse cache?

A resposta é sim, [como a documentação mesmo explica](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code):

> Deno caches remote imports in a special directory specified by the DENO_DIR environment variable. It defaults to the system's cache directory if DENO_DIR is not specified. The next time you run the program, no downloads will be made. If the program hasn't changed, it won't be recompiled either.

*Traduzindo*:

> Deno armazena em cache as importações remotas em um diretório especial especificado pela variável de ambiente `DENO_DIR`. O padrão é o diretório de cache do sistema se `DENO_DIR` não for especificado. Na próxima vez que você executar o programa, **nenhum download será feito novamente**. Se o programa não mudou, também não será recompilado.

Mas achei estranho que mesmo sem passar a flag `--allow-net`, ele acessou a internet e baixou os pacotes. Pelo visto este privilégio e padrão na hora de realizar os *imports*.