# Como criar um fallback na importação de arquivos CSS?

Tags: javascript

Em [Como devo trabalhar em relaçao a links do Bootstrap e JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/303645/5878), acerca de como servir os arquivos de mídia, seja via servidor de CDN ou servidor local, foi respondido que é interessante manter os dois: inicialmente carregando o arquivo a partir do CDN e, em caso de falha, ter um *fallback* no servidor local, tal como é feito com jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Com arquivos JavaScript, criar este *fallback* é trivial, pois basta verificar a existência do objeto, tal como em `window.jQuery || ...`, mas com outros arquivos, tais como CSS e imagens, isso não é tão trivial.

**Então como é possível definir um *fallback* para importação de arquivos CSS?**

A ideia seria ter como resultado algo semelhante à:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>bootstrapLoaded || document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">')</script>
```

[O que significa o termo Fallback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152503/5878)

Comment: No caso de Bootstrap particularmente vc pode fazer igual fez com o jQuery, só que buscando algum método usado no JS do Bootstrap. Se esse JS do Bootstrap falhar, provavelmente o CDN do CSS também vai falhar, ai vc já chama o JS que falhou e o CSS também! Essa opção não serve exclusivamente para qq CSS, mas funciona para o Bootstrap e outros frameworks que tenho JS e CSS no mesmo CDN. Se não ficar claro me fala que bolo uma resposta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Que browsers queres suportar? A opção de carregar todos os script dinamicamente é válida ou queres mesmo fallbacks para scrips estáticos no HTML?

Comment: @Sergio carregar dinamicamente é válido. Se houver prós/contras, seria legal listá-los.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a **[documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events)** você pode usar o evento `onerror` na tag `link` que carrega o CSS. Caso haja falha no carregamento do arquivo, você pode chamar uma função JavaScript no evento:

```
                                                     evento     chama a função
                                                        ↓             ↓
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//...arquivoRemoto.css" onerror="cssNaoCarregado()" />
```

Na função, você insere no `head` da página a tag `<link>` com o arquivo local:

```
<script>
function cssNaoCarregado(){
   var css = document.createElement("link");
   css.rel = "stylesheet";
   css.href = "arquivoLocal.css";
   document.querySelector("head").appendChild(css);
}
</script>
```

> **Nota:** não funciona nos navegadores da Microsoft. Nesses navegadores, mesmo  que o arquivo não tenha sido carregado, ele chama o evento `onload` (`<link rel="stylesheet" onload="função()"...>`), como se tivesse sido carregado.

Answer (score 3):

Testa a quantidade de regras do css escolhido, 
O script que deixo a seguir testa unicamente um css se foi carregado, fica a seu critério se deseja testar mais de um crie um array de objetos com o caminho dos css externo que deseja testar e o css local relacionado, e percorra com um for para testar de um a um.
Ex:

```
var cssTestar = [{externo: "caminhoexterno", local: "caminholocal"},{externo: "caminhoexterno", local: "caminholocal"}];
```

Recomendo colocar o seguinte bloco de javascript como último elemento do head;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        if (!sheet.href) {
            continue;
        }
        if(sheet.href=='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrapnaoexiste.min.css') {
            var qtdRules = 0;
            try {
                var rules = sheet.hasOwnProperty("rules") && sheet.rules ? sheet.rules : (sheet.hasOwnProperty("cssRules") ? sheet.cssRules : []);
                qtdRules = rules.length;
            } finally {
                if (qtdRules == 0) {
                    var link = document.createElement('link');
                    link.id = 'id';
                    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
                    link.type = "text/css";
                    link.href = "caminholocal/seucsslocal.css";
                    document.head.appendChild(link);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Exemplo no snippet: Obs.: ao executar não apresenta nada no quadro de resultado mas se inspecionar o mesmo verá a tag link com o "csslocal" criado no head;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrapnaoexiste.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type="text/javascript">
 for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
  var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
     if (!sheet.href) {
         continue;
     }
    if(sheet.href=='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrapnaoexiste.min.css') {
     var qtdRules = 0;
      try {
    var rules = sheet.hasOwnProperty("rules") && sheet.rules ? sheet.rules : (sheet.hasOwnProperty("cssRules") ? sheet.cssRules : []);
    qtdRules = rules.length;
   } finally {
    if (qtdRules == 0) {
     var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.id = 'id';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "caminholocal/seucsslocal.css";
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }
   }
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```