# Devo tratar e-mails como case sensitive ou insensitive?

Tags: email, ux

É comum termos um cadastro, principalmente de *login* que pede um endereço de e-mail. De acordo com a RFC que rege [e-mails](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) e [domínios](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) o primeiro é *case sensitive*, enquanto que o segundo é *insensitive*, o que neste caso facilita bastante.

O problema é que o usuário não é obrigado saber a RFC e respeitar isso tanto quanto cadastra seu e-mail quanto quando usa o endereço para algo no sistema (*login* por exemplo), e aí já sabe, se você seguir a RFC dará erro para o usuário que ele está usando e-mail errado quando pra ele não está errado, os caracteres são, pra ele, visualmente os mesmos.

A solução simples é mandar a RFC pra #$@%&*! e considerar que e-mails são *case insensitive*. Não sem um problema, embora raro, pode ser que tenha dois e-mails diferentes com o texto igual quando não observamos a caixa deles.

Então qual dos dois deveriam ser usados? Tem uma especificação ou recomendação que pode ser considerada universal?

**Escolhendo tratar como a RFC manda o que fazer quando o usuário coloca o e-mail cadastrado de forma errada?** Lembrando que o errado pode ser o que ele cadastrou (talvez ambos estejam errados).

**Escolhendo tratar sem sensibilidade de caixa, o que fazer quando tiver dois e-mails ambíguos quando isso acontecer?**

Lembro que apresentar e-mails cadastrados no seu sistema para desambiguar pode ser uma brecha de privacidade ou mesmo segurança.

Exigir muita coisa no momento do cadastro pode afugentar um usuário que está entrando no seu sistema.

Eu tenho algumas ideais do que fazer, mas uma solução criativa seria ainda mais útil, mesmo que dê um pouco mais de trabalho mas tenha um [*fallback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152503/101) para não criar muito problema.

A pergunta é sobre a ambiguidade de endereços de e-mail.

Comment: Em todos os sistemas nos quais já trabalhei sempre converti os endereços de e-mail para minúsculas. Acredito que os provedores devam fazer o mesmo, já que não lembro de ter visto em maiúsculas...

Answer (score 1):

Especificação ou recomendação considerada universal é a RFC (como bem apontou). O restante e qualquer outra abordagem vai do gosto do freguês.

Se você enviar um e-mail para os servidores da Apple (meu caso) ou criar um Apple ID, não importa se está em *uppercase* ou *lowercase*. Eles são tratados como um único endereço. Eu posso logar em qualquer um dos serviços deles com uppercase ou não. O mesmo acontece com o Gmail/Google (o exemplo na imagem anexa mostra isso).

Diante disso, se eu estivesse em sua pele com este problema, minha abordagem seria:

1. Testar os grandes provedores de e-mail (Gmail, Apple, Hotmail, UOL) e entender como se comportam com essa questão. Se para eles não interessa a "caixa", normatizava tudo em minúsculas.
2. Pequenos provedores ou endereços "estranhos", deixaria como o usuário digitou mas faria um fallback para autenticação.

Não consigo ver uma "bala de prata" na questão, porém a probabilidade de existirem dois endereços de e-mail similares cuja única diferença é a caixa de um caractere é muito remota e não sinto que vale a pena dispêndio de muito pensar no assunto.

Saudações

[image: Exemplo de "diferentes" endereços]

Answer (score -1):

Existe provedores hoje que aceitam emails com caixa alta e são case sensitive.

Nestes provedores, caso você trocar Uppercase para Lowercase ou vice-versa, ele não ira aceitar seu login, afinal ele é case sensitive.

Nos projetos que trabalhei, eu optei por ser case sensitive, afinal é o mesmo que ele irá usar no seu provedor para logar, e quando eu disparar qualquer comunicação via email a este usuário até mesmo para confirmação de conta, eu tinha garantia que o email chegará se estiver digitado correto.

Existe diversas aplicações onde a regra pode mudar... Para comunicações onde o usuário apenas digitou seu email para receber promoções e afins, e o mesmo não é um cliente concreto, apenas uma possibilidade e não tem como ter certeza que o mesmo digitou correto seu endereço de email, poderá ser viável não usar case sensitive.

Outro ponto é, se sua aplicação que digere a informação do cliente, e ela é muito acessada por dispositivos moveis, possivelmente o teclado já inicia a primeira letra como maiúscula, o que poderá ocasionar divergência do email real, nesse caso talvez seja mais efetivo e talvez traga maior alcance de comunicação prevendo que todos serão lowercase. OU até mesmo aplicar uma regra para receber e prever esse dado.

De toda forma, sei que não respondi de forma concreta e apenas hipóteses para este problema.

A conclusão é que, a escolha entre a forma de digerir essa informação, depende de onde ela está sendo aplicada, e para o que pode ser usada posteriormente.

Comment: Olá, Breno. É bom vc participar e contribuir, mas da forma como ficou seu post parece mais um relato pessoal (que não funciona muito bem no nosso modelo, daria mais certo em fóruns) do que uma resposta técnica. Lembre-se que a qualquer momento pode  [edit] e aprimorar o post (quem sabe traçando prós e contras das possívels soluções). Uma lida em [Tour] e [Help], e em outras postagens com respostas bem pontuadas pode ajudar a se familiarizar com o modelo do site.