# Qual a utilidade dessa linha?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu pretendo saber o que esta linha de código dentro do meu HTML faz? Por que quando eu a elimino o site para de funcionar?

```
<script src="js/main.js?nocache=<?php echo md5(microtime()) ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Essa linha importa um script passando um parâmetro `nocache` cujo valor é definido por `md5(microtime())` vindo do php.

Comment: Isso significa que o modelo que vc pegou é cheio de gambiarra. Primeiro, se o site para inteiro, é pq depende tudo de um JS (se for um jogo, ou aplicação muito especifica, é até compreensível. Se for um site convencional, não devia depender totalmente de JS). Segundo, que o site vai sempre recarregar o JS toda vez, pq a url muda toda hora, o que é péssimo pra banda e performance. Terceiro que a pessoa não sabe bem PHP, pq o `uniqid` é muito mais adequado pra isso e não corre o risco de colisão. Quarto, se é só pra não ter cache, não precisava escrever `nocache=`, bastaria main.js`?<?php...`.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

É improvável que o `nocache` seja necessário em algum ponto desse *script*, mas só vendo o que tem dentro dele para dizer o que. Aparentemente foi posto (como o próprio nome já diz) para o *browser* não fazer cache do *script*, pois o URL vai mudar a cada vez que a página for recarregada, e o que vale para o cache do *browser* é o conjunto todo, não apenas o `main.js`.

De qualquer forma o motivo do site parar de funcionar é que ele adotou um padrão de dependência deste *script*. O ideal é que isso não aconteça, ou seja, o site até pode não ficar no seu melhor estado mas deve funcionar assim mesmo. Existe [técnica para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101). É compreensível que o site exija a presença de JS e *scripts* específicos para funcionar bem, mas impedir completamente o uso não costuma ser uma boa ideia.