# Como fazer com que uma função execute apenas no IE 10 e 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Eu quero que um trecho de código (uma função especifica) execute apenas quando o navegador for IE 10 e 11, quando for Firefox ou Chrome por exemplo, eu quero que essa função seja ignorada. Isso é possível?

Comment: segue dica; https://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não faria isso, [leia isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101), mas se quer mesmo (não funcionará no Edge também):

```
if (/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    funcao()
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Browser/IdentifyIE10-11.js)