# O que esse if está querendo dizer?

Tags: javascript, if

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    
      #myP {
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open this page in fullscreen mode.</p>
<button onclick="openFullscreen()">Go Fullscreen Mode</button>
<button onclick="">Close Fullscreen</button>
<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.</p>
<p id="myP">I will display the event that was fired!</p>

<script>

var elem = window.document.documentElement;

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen)
  {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Esse código eu peguei do W3Schools para poder estudar, mas nesta parte:

```
if (elem.requestFullscreen)
```

Está dizendo o que? Ele não está usando nenhum operador lógico ou de comparação seria tipo, se HTML estiver em tela cheia, execute esse bloco?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ao contrário do que as pessoas acreditam o `if` apenas decide fazer algo se ele tiver um valor verdeiro, ou faz nada ou cai no `else` se ele tem um valor falso. Essa coisa de ter uma condição no `if` é uma invenção da cabeça das pessoas, ele só desvia o fluxo de execução condicionalmente de acordo com um valor, e este valor deve ser booleano, nada mais que isso. Por acaso a maioria das vezes as pessoas colocam ali uma expressão que dá como resultado um booleano, mas isso é uma coincidência. Você poderia fazer isso:

```js
if (true) console.log("ok");
```

E este bloco seria sempre executado porque sempre é verdadeiro, claro não faz sentido porque é um condicional que já se sabe o resultado.

Você pode fazer um código assim:

```js
var variavel = true;
if (variavel) console.log("ok");
```

Agora faz mais sentido porque tem uma variável que vale um booleano, mas ainda não faz tanto sentido assim porque você sabe o valor dessa variável, faria mais sentido se for uma variável que você não tem tanto controle. É o caso da variável `elem.requestFullscreen`. Ele certamente vale `true` ou `false` e você não sabe o que é, então pode entrar no `if` ou não.

Outra forma que as pessoas não entendem seria algo assim:

```js
var entrada = prompt("digita a");
var variavel = entrada == "a";
if (variavel) console.log("ok");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ConditionalFunction.js).

Percebeu que agora você não tem o controle se vai executar o bloco do `if` ou não? E eu usei uma variável para estabelecer a condição, eu não fiz no `if`. Não faz muito sentido ter essa variável, apenas fiz assim para demonstrar que a condição não pertence ao `if`, você pode fazer ela em qualquer lugar que espere uma expressão e de preferência em algum lugar que espere um resultado booleano já que o operador `==` de comparação, assim como os outros operadores de comparação, sempre resultam em um booleano (`true` ou `false`). Os operadores relacionais também resultam em um booleano, e algumas funções também, e algumas propriedades de objetos guardam booleanos.

Em resumo o `if` espera um booleano e a variável que você usou é um booleano "por tabela" (explico mais abaixo), e ali a decisão é tomada se é executado ou não. Então no seu exemplo se a pro propriedade `requestFullscreen` está verdadeira, ou seja, entendo eu que ela indica que é permitido requisitar ficar em tela cheia (mesmo que implicitamente), ele chama o método que faz ficar tela cheia.

Neste caso específico `requestFullscreen` é uma função, se ela existir ela assume o valor `true` onde se espera um booleano (JavaScript tem tipagem fraca, isso é uma maldição porque acontece um monte de coisa esquisita, mas dá essa flexibilidade), e se a função não existir ela assume `false`, por isso não entraria no `if`, afinal se a função não existe não deve executá-la. Isso chama-se [melhoria progressiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101).

Então neste caso se o navegador tem a capacidade de executara função para colocar em tela cheia ela será executada, caso contrário nada será feito. Se não usar o `if` acontecerá um erro.

Answer (score 9):

Esse `if` simplesmente verifica se a função `elem.requestFullscreen` existe, ou seja, se o navegador suporta tela cheia. Funções em JS são objetos, e objetos são convertidos para `true` em contextos que requerem valores booleanos, como o seu `if`.

Você encontra mais detalhes sobre isso na [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400325) e numa [resposta minha sobre o mesmo assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271721). Um ponto relevante no seu caso específico é que `elem` precisa existir e ser um objeto (ou conversível em objeto), caso contrário há risco de erro em tempo de execução. Se houver chance de `elem` ser `null`, seria mais seguro verificar isso antes, assim:

```
if (elem && elem.requestFullScreen) { ...
```