# O que é prolyfill?

Tags: terminologia

Já sabemos o que é um **polyfill** ([O que é Polyfill?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194857/5878)), mas o que é um **prolyfill**? Existe alguma relação dele com o próprio *polyfill*, dado que os nomes são tão semelhantes?

Vi o termo por acaso [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170/qual-a-forma-correta-de-se-fazer-uma-substitui%c3%a7%c3%a3o-regular-em-javascript-para-tod#comment4670_3716) e vi que até existem algumas referências a ele na internet, mas é pouco utilizado. O termo é pouco utilizado ou é sua implementação que pouco comum?

Comment: Eu vim quente pra fechar como dup :D

Comment: @Maniero Então circula... passa reto...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece haver uma ["informação canônica"](https://au.si/what-is-a-prolyfill) simples sobre ela por isso vou responder até porque sei que é só para termos aqui um conteúdo útil.

É basicamente o mesmo que o *polyfill*, mas ao contrário. Enquanto o termo já consagrado se encarrega de fornecer implementações que tornem seu código compatível com mecanismos antigos que ainda não possuem certa capacidade, o *prolyfill* faz o mesmo com mecanismos que ainda não existem e permitem você testar algo que poderá existir. Isto é útil para demonstrar como seria se fosse implementado para servir de base como proposta de novidade em tecnologia web ou para testar algo que já foi proposto.

Acho o termo desnecessário e até mal pensado, tanto que agora estão chamando de *polyfill* especulativo, portanto ele não deixa de ser um *polyfill* e no fundo é a mesma coisa, usa-se do mesmo jeito, tem as mesmas vantagens, a diferença é apenas que ele pode se tornar inútil facilmente porque pode não ser implementado desta forma. Ou até mesmo nunca ser implementado, portanto eles possuem apenas objetivos diferentes. Sua única utilidade é dar uma chance das pessoas testarem uma possível forma como funcionaria aquilo, é útil mais para os implementadores do que para usuários normais de tecnologias, eu não me preocuparia muito com ela, a não ser por curiosidade ou se está entrando no mundo de implementadores dessas tecnologias, especialmente web.

[Exemplo](https://github.com/ausi/cq-prolyfill). Pelas minhas pesquisas o termo parece ser usado quase exclusivamente aí :D

Comment: É basicamente um "olha que legal se fosse assim" e se der certo eventualmente passar a ser parte da implementação oficial?

Comment: Pode ser isso, então até mesmo um *start* de proposta, e pode ser "olha como será quando a proposta atual for implementada por alguém, teste e dê feedback para ajudar os implementadores e autores da proposta que ainda não foi finalizada".